# how to select a highest float value from mysql with active record class codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to select a highest float number from my database. E.g i have a software in my db with 4 different versions (like app 1.0, app 2.0, app 4.0). I want to select 4.0 using $this->db->order_by("version", "DESC") function. But it's not working. this query returns the last added version. I am using codeigniter framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version is actually a float e.g. `1.0` not `app 1.0` then you could do

`$this->db->select_max('version')->limit(1);`

See the [Active Record User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: Even if it is `app 1.0`, using `order_by('version', 'DESC')->limit(1)` should work. I think `ASC` is default.